# this code uses the address of type?

Tags: go

the code at https://code.google.com/p/goauth2/source/browse/oauth/oauth.go#99 declares this type:

```
package oauth
...
type Config struct {...}
...
```

the suggested use of this is following:

```
var config = &oauth.Config{...}
```

I do not understand why this code takes the address of this type and why this is even possible in Go. I am a newbie. I thought that types are for the compiler, no? Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> [The Go Programming Language Specification](http://golang.org/ref/spec)
>
> [Composite literals](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Composite_literals)
>
> Composite literals construct values for structs, arrays, slices, and
>   maps and create a new value each time they are evaluated. They consist
>   of the type of the value followed by a brace-bound list of composite
>   elements. An element may be a single expression or a key-value pair.
>
> Given the declaration
>
> ```
> type Point3D struct { x, y, z float64 }
> ```
>
> one may write
>
> ```
> origin := Point3D{}         // zero value for Point3D
> ```
>
> Taking the address of a composite literal generates a pointer to a
>   unique instance of the literal's value.
>
> ```
> var pointer *Point3D = &Point3D{y: 1000}
> ```

It's an example of the use of a pointer to a composite literal.

Answer (score 3):

This is taking the address of a new instance of the `Config` type, not the address of the type itself.

Comment: where is this new instance created?

Comment: `oauth.Config{...}` is the syntax to initialise a new value of type `oauth.Config`.